# Convert Extended character to int in csharp

Tags: c#, vb6, extended-ascii

I had to copy an encryption, decryption function from VB6 to csharp. I am running into a problem with extended ascii characters. As an example, the character in question has an Extended ASCII value of 155 (looks like a smaller version of the '>').

I learned from my Google searches that there are many extended ascii versions (pages?) but I just need the standard Latin-1 shown here http://www.ascii-code.com/

But I could not find a clear way to do what I need. What I need is a way to get the value 155 (and any others in the extended set) from the character. VB6 does this with a simple Asc(String) statement. I just need a way to emulate this statement in csharp.

Comment: Pull the char from the string and cast it as int.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the value it gives is 8250 - not 155. This is the value of the unicode character (2 bytes not 1)

Comment: Sorry cast it as byte

Comment: Then you just get the first byte which is something like 64 (I can't remember exactly). See the answer below for the solution. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
string str = "›";
var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
var values = encoding.GetBytes(str); //Result is { 155 }
```

The trick here is to get an encoding object for the `Windows-1252` code page, then use `GetBytes` to convert the string into a byte array.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I just figured it out right before I looked at your answer. The trick was to Google 'csharp get char from extended ascii' instead of the other way around. Anyway thank you again!

Comment: Actually VB6 uses the "ANSI" codepage - i.e. the setting for non-Unicode programs on Control Panel on the computer where the code is running. This will not be 1252 on every computer. So a strict conversion from VB6 to C# would use [`System.Text.Encoding.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx) not GetEncoding(1252)

Comment: MarkJ you are a mind reader! I saw the Default property on the Encoding namespace and wondered if I should use that instead. I came here just to check up on my question and saw your comment. I will have to run all my tests again but that's better than revisiting this issue. Thank you!

Comment: 50,000 randomly generated strings of different lengths all encrypted the same in VB6 and C# using the Encoding.Default! Thanks everyone.